# accessing db using greendao across application

Tags: android, greendao

I've started learning and using greendao ORM and I have this issue.
I'm writing a memo / alert application and this means I need access to the DB from various activities and also services and receivers.
For example: on one screen I'm setting the alerts' values.
On a service and a receiver I'm reading those values and act accordingly.

the setup and DB access with objects and relations seem to be working fine from inside my main activity oncreate() as i've just setup the coder there to test and debug.

I thought of writing a singleton class that will handle all DB access and operations, but as it's not an activity it has no "context"
I am aware that passing context as a parameter is a bad idea.
I need to find a way to have DB access from all of the above mentioned.

Also, I've read somewhere that I should not initialise the DB in the main activity.
Can someone elaborate on that and explain the idea of initialization and the problem with the main activity?

Hope I was able to clear my issues.
Thanks for reading and possibly answering.

Comment: You can use the application context, which is a singleton for the lifetime of your process. `context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Thanks @Karakuri, but context is not immediately available to me in services or helper classes.

Comment: I read that passing context as a parameter leads to leakage.
And the main issue is how to get to the context when it's unavailable

Comment: The only way your code could be running is if the system has started an `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, or `ContentProvider` belonging to your app; each of those either is itself a `Context` or has access to one.  Or you can use your own subclass of `Application`, because if your application process is running at all then your `Application` will have to exist, and `Application` is itself also a `Context`. Passing something as a parameter isn't a leak; holding onto it when it should be disposed of by the system is a leak.

Comment: Thank you so much, again, @Karakuri

Comment: I have quite a few gaps in my knowledge so I am asking what may seem to be simple questions.
I want the DB access handled in a singleton helper class. So if I understand you correctly, either I pass context to it, or i make it extend application.
what would be the preferred way?
also, as a singleton, would it be better to pass the context of the main activity when it starts, or provide the context of every activity / service calling the helper class?
Last question for now... how or what would be the best way to dispose of context so it will not leak?

Answer (score 0):

Leaking a Context means you've kept a reference to a `Context` beyond its normal lifecycle--usually an `Activity` that has been finished or a `Service` that has been stopped. Passing a `Context` as a method argument does not mean there is a leak. It's only a leak if you save a reference to that `Context` in a field and keep it beyond the point that the system wants to destroy it (so your reference prevents it from being garbage collected). The same can happen if you keep a reference to something else that keeps a reference to a `Context`, the prime example of which is a `View`.

There is an application `Context` that lives as long as your application process does, and is always a singleton. Holding a reference to it is not a leak. This means you can use it in your singleton database helper class without worrying it will leak. Your singleton can actually accept any `Context` because you can simply call `.getApplicationContext()` on it to get this application context instance.

Subclassing `Application` is optional. In my opinion, the benefit of doing so is using the application's `onCreate()` method to do any one-time setup since this is your first opportunity to run application code.

Here is a great article on `Context`s that might be useful: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/